# html popup containing flash to automatically acquire focus

Tags: html, flash, focus, popupwindow

I have a web page with a button that opens up a popup page like this:

```
<input type = "button" value = "Start" onclick = 'window.open("path/to/html/page", "some_name", "type=fullWindow,fullscreen,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,status=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no")'")' >
```

The popup points to an html page that contains a frameset, which in turn has one frame that loads a flash file. This flash contains some interaction elements (similar to textbox input).

Once the popup opens, typing on the keyboard does nothing; you have to click on the flash file to actually bring it to focus so that it intercepts keyboard input. Is there a way to make this happen automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the page has been rendered, use

`document.getElementById("flashID").focus();`

in the page that is bieng loaded. ( Where **flashID** is the id of the swf in the page. )

But then there is no one way to do this across all browsers...

---

I found [this link](http://dougr.net/2011/07/05/automatically-setting-swf-object-focus/) & [this discussion](http://dougr.net/2011/07/05/automatically-setting-swf-object-focus/) relating to your query. Perhaps they could help.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on Chromium... do you any browser that this could work on?

Comment: Thanks for the links and assistance, I believe I'll find my way through now